# Flask module not found even though it's installed

Tags: python, flask

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1RJmh_OqeA) python tutorial on flask, I have created the virtual environment and the code runs fine without issues. But when I open an interactive shell inside the virtual environment and type:

```
from app import db
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Repo\flask todo app\app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

When I try to install flask it says it's already installed, I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

The full console output:

```
(venv) C:\Repo\flask todo app>python3
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from app import db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Repo\flask todo app\app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

The code in `app.py`:

```
from email.policy import default
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    completed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task {}>'.format(self.id)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Note: I can see `flask.exe` under this path:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
```

But it seems like I am using python 3.10.2 version in the shell, not sure if it's relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I see that you are running `python3` in your console... and that's it! Remember that you have to select a program to open. You should run `python3 <your_program_name>` instead.

Still, it will be easier for you to use the `flask shell` instead. To use it, run the `flask shell` command from your project directory while inside the virtual environment.

To access your project variables using the `flask shell` you have to create a `shell_context_processor` as follows:

```py
# Insert this between your route definitions and the run statement

@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context_processor():
    # The dictionary below will include any variable you want to access from the flask shell. Eventually you'll want to include here, for example, your database models
    return dict(db = db )
```

Miguel Grinberg (the author of an excellent Flask book and several courses) has an [excellent entry in his blog where he explains the shell context processor in detail](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database/page/0) Do take a look at it (go to the "*Shell Context*" part, after the one titled "*Playing with the database*") and feel free to check his other entries if you have any other doubts with Flask.

Comment: did this change between python 3.6 and 3.10 ? it seems the tutorial is using python 3.6, btw thanks for sharing the article, will definitely check it out!

Comment: @SelmanGenç I edited my answer. What do you refer to when you say "this"?

Comment: I mean accessing the variable from shell. it seems my problem is not accessing the db variable, I get error in flask import statement when I try to run app.py in shell, even though it runs without error when I run the app with "flask run"

Comment: btw I saw your edit, if I run "python3 app.py" I still get the same module not found error

Comment: I understand. Can you run `pip freeze` on your shell while inside the virtual environment and paste the outcome here?

Comment: (env) C:\Repo\flask todo app>pip freeze
autopep8==1.6.0
click==8.0.4
colorama==0.4.4
Flask==2.0.3
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
greenlet==1.1.2
itsdangerous==2.1.1
Jinja2==3.0.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
pycodestyle==2.8.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.32
toml==0.10.2
Werkzeug==2.0.3

Comment: Good. `pip freeze` tells you which packages are installed and, as you can see, Flask is installed. Try the following:
1) Run `python3`
2) Once inside the interpreter, run `from app import app`
**Keep in mind that you have to be inside the directory that stores the `app.py` file**

Comment: I have tried, it's the same error. though I did it inside the virtualenv, should I do it outside?

Answer (score 0):

Do you ensure the installation  is ok? If not, please check it and ensure it.[install flask on windows](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-flask)

Comment: What exactly does "ensure the installation is ok" mean?

Comment: I mean. ensure the flask of installation is ok, you can  read here http://docs.jinkan.org/docs/flask/installation.html